# Magento Onepage Checkout Place Order button redirects to empty cart instead to success page

Tags: magento, checkout

I have an issue, and can not find what is causing it. On my local machine everything is working fine but when moved code to staging server on place order button, I'm getting redirected to empty cart page. I have looked system.log and exceptions.log, and also inspected through firebug, but I can't find anything. Did anybody had similar issue, or know how to fix this. Thanks
BTW it is Magento EE 1.14

Comment: do you have php encrypt  installed on server , if its not than that can be the issue.

Comment: Problem solved, for some reason on staging server what was causing a problem was USE SID IN FRONTEND, after I have disable it everything was back to normal. There was no this issue on production server. So there must be sosmething with server settings.